# Why *pointer_name behaves differently in 1D and 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why is it that when `*q` is used in 1D array it gives the value in the array whereas `*p` in 2D array gives an address instead. Isn't `*pointer_name` supposed to tell what is stored, so why is output an address instead of `40` (the value in array)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a[3][4] = {  
  {40, 1, 2, 3} ,   
  {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   
  {8, 9, 10, 11}   
 };
 int (*p)[4] = a;

 int b[4] = {3,4,8,5};
 int  *q = b;

 printf("%d, %d",*q, *p);// output- 3, 10485040

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It very well behaves the same! It is your premise which is wrong. What is the first entry of a **2**D array? And then implicit conversions are applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `p` is a pointer to an array. When you dereference `p` the array will decay to a pointer to the first element. Doing `*p` and `&(*p)[0]` is equivalent (and also equivalent to `&a[0][0]`).

If you want to print the first element then you need to dereference *both* pointers, i.e. `**p`.

Comment: Or use array notiation, which is more within the semantics: `p[0][0]`. `**p` is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

2D array means an array of arrays! so each slot of first row in the 2D array should have the address of another array.

for instance if you have an array `a[2][3]` , the `a[0]` value is the address of the first slot of an array with size 4. and `a[1]` like so  etc .